# How to show battery percentage on battery icon in task bar without hovering or clicking?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

I want to show battery percentage on battery icon in the task bar.

Currently it appears this way.

[image: Battery icon in task bar]

I cannot see charge left percentage unless I click or hover over the icon.

[image: Hover over Battery icon in task bar]

[image]

What I have in mind is OS X like battery icon.

[image: Battery icon in OS X task bar]

How can it be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I developed a simple open-source alternative to solve this exact problem.

Percentage is downloadable from the GitHub repository at https://github.com/kas/percentage.

You can compile the application with Visual Studio or download the executable file from the releases tab in the GitHub repository page.

Here is what the new tray application icon looks like in my GPD Win device:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with the onboard tool in Windows10. But there is a 3rd party tool called [BatteryBar Pro](https://batterybarpro.com/) which displays an battery icon in the taskbar.

[image]